# dlsym -- get overridden symbol

Tags: c, unix, symbols, dlopen, dlsym

I have an application dynamically loading libraries which dynamically load libraries which...

In Windows, I'm able to iterate over all loaded modules looking for the symbol I'm interested in. Don't know how to do that in Unix/Linux environment. I know I may use `dlsym(dlopen(0, flag))` or `dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT / RTLD_NEXT)` for first two symbols and know the order of the modules to search in -- just how may I get deeper and get all definitions of given symbol?

Answer (score 6):

To find a symbol in a shard object, open it with `dlopen`.

```
 void* foobar = dlopen ("/usr/local/lib/foobar.so", RTLD_NOW);
 void* mysymbol = dlsym (foobar, "mysymbol");
```

**Update** Here's a program that iterates over all symbols named "foo". This is not POSIX but GNU libs. I am almost sure POSIX does not provide such capabilities.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <link.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void doit (const char* s)
{
    void* obj = dlopen (s, RTLD_LAZY);
    void* fcn = dlsym (obj, "foo");
    if (fcn)
        printf ("Object %s has 'foo' at addr %p\n", *s ? s : "(exe)", fcn);
}    
int cb (struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data)
{
    doit (info->dlpi_name);
    return 0;
}    
int main ()
{
    dl_iterate_phdr (cb, 0);    
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Object (exe) has 'foo' at addr 0xb76f8418
Object (exe) has 'foo' at addr 0xb76f8418
Object /tmp/libfoo.so has 'foo' at addr 0xb76f8418
Object /tmp/libfoo1.so has 'foo' at addr 0xb76f5418
Object /tmp/libfoo2.so has 'foo' at addr 0xb76f2418
```

There are some duplicates but this is a minor problem.

Comment: FWIW - RLTD_NOW kind of  undermines the use of RLTD_LAZY, which is what dlopen() uses during image activation.

Comment: Yeah, right. Probably should have specified it more clearly in the question -- I need to extract it from the process' symbol tables. I'm able to get the first symbol with given name from the process itself or two first symbols having that name from the current scope (which may be different when called from within a library). And I would like to be able to iterate over all symbols having that name using standard POSIX functions. As I haven't found the solution anywhere, I wonder if it's possible.

Comment: Thank you! That (posix issue) is what I was afraid of. Thank you for an answer, will search the same for the unices (I believe I have been doing something quite similar for AIX couple of months ago, searching for platform-specific solution for other OSes shouldn't be a big deal, but need not to say, portable solution would be far more convenient).

Answer (score 2):

Answering own question to make the life of people searching for the solution easier.
There's no unified way, one wanting to iterate on loaded modules should search for the following commands/data types (the experts are invite to comment on that):

Windows:
 MODULEENTRY32, CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, Module32First, Module32Next

Linux:
 as described in n.m.'s answer, return non-zero from the callback when proper module found (ends the loop).

AIX:
 loadquery(L_GETINFO,  buffer, size), struct ld_info.

HP-UX:
 dlget, dlgetname (if you need the module path).

Solaris:
 ldinfo, Link_map.

Additionally, I'd recommend to dlopen the modules and get the symbol from a new handle to have library's reference count incremented which prevents it from being unloaded. At least on AIX it may have a side effect of the library loaded and initialized once again, but it's in most cases better than attempting to call a function from the unloaded library.